# What is the meaning of 放 fàng in this idiom?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, glyph-origin

The meaning of 放 fàng from dictionary is “put, release”.

“Put or place” is an entirely opposite word / antonym of “release, free, liberate”

Then what does 放 mean in the following idiom:

> 放在心上 fàngzàixīnshàng “to take to heart”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 'To put; to place' and 'to release' are not entirely antonymous. The original logic in the character `放` is that you *release* something from your hand such that it is *placed* on a receptacle.
2. It can be literal, as in `他放下錢便走了` ('He left after putting down some money'); or figurative, as in `別放在心上`.
3. To be precise, you are advised 'not to put *something* on your heart'. Let us hypothesise and say `她的死` (her death) is the object, as in 'don't take her death to heart'. We can say `別放她的死在心上`, but it sounds better if we use the `把`-construction, as in `別把她的死放在心上`. The object is thus usually fronted in the sentence, which may be a source of your confusion.